# How to normalize eigen faces in facial recognition?

Tags: c#, pca, face-recognition, alglib

what is ||u||=1 in PCA algorithm for face recognition?

Comment: What is saying `||u||=1`? Are you running some code that is producing that as a result and it's unexpected?  Or are you saying you don't understand something written about the algorithm written on the site you linked to?

Comment: Actually i want to know what is ||u||=1 as given in that website.@jinglesthula

Answer (score 0):

Based on what you described (very limited though), ||u||=1 means your principal component size should be 1.

But why should its size be 1?

Because you are going to project your data to the principal component (PC). And if you don't have the principal component whose size is 1, then your projection will be multiplied by the PC's size. You want to project your data to the eigenvector, without stretching the data. Hope this help!